# How to set a origin cookie in a browser

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I am trying to test a website for a travel service. I need to set the origin cookie of the browser to "New York" to test it. It automatically recognizes the origin as "Washington" without the setup. I am testing it on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Server sets the cookie initially, maybe you can try to alter it:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/cookies
Or use a chrome plugin like 'edit this cookie' or something like that.
Otherwise you could try to send requests with postman, but that wouldn't use the Website... only the server.